# Why setting up networkd to a static IP does not work?

Tags: debian, virtualbox, systemd, bitnami

After deploying a virtual appliance inside VirtualBox, the guest has a DHCP IP address and everything works fine. The problem is that I need to have this VM on a static IP address.

This VM is the latest [Bitnami Postgres](https://bitnami.com/stack/postgresql/virtual-machine), running on Debian 11.

When performing `ifconfig`, I get this for the relevant network interface :

```
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.196  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe5e:6c9  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:5e:06:c9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1431  bytes 113648 (110.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 244  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 306  bytes 22928 (22.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 19  base 0xd000
```

I have tried following the vendor's [recommended steps](https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/faq/configuration/configure-static-address/) to assign a static IP address, namely by adding the file `/etc/systemd/network/25-wired.network`, however this does not work :

```
[Match]
Name=enp0s3

[Network]
Address=192.168.2.52
Gateway=192.168.1.1
```

As indicated by the DHCP result, the subnet is `255.255.255.0` (or `192.168.2.52/24`) so I changed the config file to :

```
[Match]
Name=enp0s3

[Network]
Address=192.168.2.52/24
Gateway=192.168.1.1
```

But then it complains that the `Gateway` is not on the same subnet! Changing it to :

```
[Match]
Name=enp0s3

[Network]
Address=192.168.2.52/16
Gateway=192.168.1.1
```

yields no error when restarting the network service, however routing is broken and nothing is accessible; the guest can't ping any machine, and no machine can ping the guest!

I tried adding various sections, like `Route]`, `[Address]`, etc. I am at a loss.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.
 Hover over the systemd and virtualbox tags and read those popups. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic.

Comment: Not a purist. Just following the rules. virtualbox and systemd questions get closed and deleted all the time here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define your subnet to be at `192.168.2.0/24`, witch excludes the possibility to include your gateway at `192.168.1.1` !

The correction done by the system is *correct*: Indeed, the mask for that IP/Gateway configuration is `16`, or `netmask>24`.

You should review your desired network configuration, and remember that the netmask 24 will define a minimum subnet address of `x.y.z.1` -> `x.y.z.254` . In both cases `x.y.z` remain the same.

Your gateway needs to be inside of the subnet. If you really want to use the IP `192.168.2.196` with the gateway at `192.168.1.1`, try the netmask `23`. That being said: I doubt that your gateway uses the netmask `23` (seems a standard router configuration to me).

Comment: You are right, even if the gateway is really at `182.168.1.1`, there is another gateway at `192.168.2.1` redirecting to the other one, I had to add routes to it, and it worked. Thanks.